# Avoid Radio Button selection change by keyboard with up or down keys

Tags: html, selection

I have 5 radio buttons. After I select first radio button if I press up or down keyword button, the radio button selection will change. How can I avoid changing radio selection by keyboard? With Google Chrome I don't have this problem, this problem occurs only in Firefox or Internet Explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="radio" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" value="radio" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" value="radio" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5" value="radio" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this java related? And why is it a problem to you?

Comment: Save my code in a new html file. Run the html file in IE or Firefox. Select first radio button. Press down key. I want to avoid radio button selection change by keyboard with up or down keys.

Comment: Why do you want that? That's bad practice, you should let the user his freedom, if you don't have a very good reason.

Comment: This is not a bad practice. I want the selection be made only by MOUSE. If I have a large height page, and user wants to scroll the page down by down-arrow key his selection will be changed. This is very frustrating for users.

Comment: I will repeat: this problem occurs only in IE / Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I had used a jQuery plugin to create custom radio and checkbox.
For example:
http://line25.com/articles/jquery-plugins-for-styling-checkbox-radio-buttons